# find each different value by ID and data

Tags: sql

I have a sql table that updates the status of users on a weekly cadence, i.e.

```
user_id     date           status
101         2022-04-01     asleep
101         2022-04-08     asleep
101         2022-04-15     awake
102         2022-04-01     awake
102         2022-04-08     asleep
102         2022-04-15     asleep
```

I need to narrow the results to only include the rows where the `status` column has a different value than the prior week, by user id; so in the sample above, all I actually want is:

```
user_id     date           status
101         2022-04-01     asleep
101         2022-04-15     awake
102         2022-04-01     awake
102         2022-04-08     asleep
```

The in-between weeks where the status is the same from week to week are not important; I only want to see a row if the user's status is different than it was in the week before.

Comment: Which database are you using,`mssql` or `mysql`?

Comment: it's inside Snowflake, which uses ANSI (forgive the ignorance and apologies if this doesn't answer your question @flyingfox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LAG()` to peek at a previous row according to some criteria. Then, filtering is easy.

For example, you can do:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*, lag(status) over(partition by user_id order by date) as prev_status
  from t
) x
where status <> prev_status
```